# How to filter with multiple condition text input in Ag-Grid?

Tags: ag-grid

Using ag-grid-enterprise v5.4.0

[image: multi textFilter]

create multiple textFilter input ex: [CONTAINS] filterText AND [NOT CONTAIN] filterText2 just like Excel data analysis

but both filterType2 and filterText are **undefined** after click [APPLY FILTER]

https://embed.plnkr.co/4nAjGKmChqJiRcqz6E2n/

Comment: If you could include some code, or create a js fiddle or plunker that would be great

Comment: yes please see the above code link, i cant reproduce my env but its similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do would be best achieved with the [Filter Component](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/?framework=javascript#gsc.tab=0). This allows you full control of the filter pain, whether you are in enterprise or not. Here are the **required** methods for each custom filter:

```
function CustomFilter() {}

CustomFilter.prototype.init = function (params) {
    //Put any initial functions you need here (such as setting values to null)
};

CustomFilter.prototype.getGui = function () {
    //return a string of HTML or a DOM element/node
};

CustomFilter.prototype.doesFilterPass = function (params) {
    //Logic for your custom Filter
    //return True if the row should display, false otherwise
};

CustomFilter.prototype.isFilterActive = function () {
    //logic for displaying the filter icon in the header
};

CustomFilter.prototype.getModel = function() {
    //store the filter state
};

CustomFilter.prototype.setModel = function(model) {
    //restore the filter state here
};
```

Here is an example of how to implement an "Includes x but Excludes y" filter:

```
function DoubleFilter() {
}

DoubleFilter.prototype.init = function (params) {
    this.valueGetter = params.valueGetter;
    this.filterText = null;
    this.setupGui(params);
};

// not called by ag-Grid, just for us to help setup
DoubleFilter.prototype.setupGui = function (params) {
    this.gui = document.createElement('div');
    this.gui.innerHTML =
        '<div style="padding: 4px; width: 200px;">' +
        '<div style="font-weight: bold;">Custom Athlete Filter</div>' +
        'Include: <div><input style="margin: 4px 0px 4px 0px;" type="text" id="includesText" placeholder="Includes..."/></div>' +
        'Exclude: <div><input style="margin: 4px 0px 4px 0px;" type="text" id="excludesText" placeholder="Excludes..."/></div>' +
        '</div>';

    // add listeners to both text fields
    this.eIncludesText = this.gui.querySelector('#includesText');
    this.eIncludesText.addEventListener("changed", listener);
    this.eIncludesText.addEventListener("paste", listener);
    this.eIncludesText.addEventListener("input", listener);
    // IE doesn't fire changed for special keys (eg delete, backspace), so need to
    // listen for this further ones
    this.eIncludesText.addEventListener("keydown", listener);
    this.eIncludesText.addEventListener("keyup", listener);

    this.eExcludesText = this.gui.querySelector('#excludesText');
    this.eExcludesText.addEventListener("changed", listener2);
    this.eExcludesText.addEventListener("paste", listener2);
    this.eExcludesText.addEventListener("input", listener2);
    // IE doesn't fire changed for special keys (eg delete, backspace), so need to
    // listen for this further ones
    this.eExcludesText.addEventListener("keydown", listener2);
    this.eExcludesText.addEventListener("keyup", listener2);

    var that = this;
    function listener(event) {
        that.includesText = event.target.value;
        params.filterChangedCallback();
    }
    function listener2(event) {
        that.excludesText = event.target.value;
        params.filterChangedCallback();
    }
};

DoubleFilter.prototype.getGui = function () {
    return this.gui;
};

DoubleFilter.prototype.doesFilterPass = function (params) {
    var passed = true;
    var valueGetter = this.valueGetter;
    var include = this.includesText;
    var exclude = this.excludesText;
    var value = valueGetter(params).toString().toLowerCase();

    return value.indexOf(include) >= 0 && (value.indexOf(exclude) < 0 || exclude == '') ;
};

DoubleFilter.prototype.isFilterActive = function () {
    return (this.includesText !== null && this.includesText !== undefined && this.includesText !== '')
        || (this.excludesText !== null && this.excludesText !== undefined && this.excludesText !== '');
};

DoubleFilter.prototype.getModel = function() {
    var model = {
        includes: this.includesText.value,
        excludes: this.excludesText.value
    };
    return model;
};

DoubleFilter.prototype.setModel = function(model) {
    this.eIncludesText.value = model.includes;
    this.eExcludesText.value = model.excludes;
};
```

Here is a [modified plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/4vfw673pPuhCD5wcNrAl/). I placed the filter just on the Athlete column, but the `DoubleFilter` can be applied to any column once it is created.

**EDIT:**

I realized you were asking for a rather generic double filter in your question with "Includes and Excludes" as an example. Here is a [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/usuvzLzvyck2h0n9NMt2/) that has a more generic double filter.

Comment: what if multi column filters together?  i think should implement apply function but doesn't work? please see https://embed.plnkr.co/NcJzmUMWIaWMA7PauUiL/

Comment: @YuqiLi The plunker that you have linked seems to work fine with the apply button on multiple columns...

Comment: cuz i send filtermodel to paging function...that doesn't work $scope.gridOptions.api.getFilterModel(); do i have to implement setModel or setApi?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would need to implement the `customFilter.prototype.getModel` to include anything that your custom filter is using to filter on. from that you would need to declare what the two text fields and the two select boxes. Then in the `customFilter.prototype.setModel` you would accept that object and set up the filter from there

Comment: @YuqiLi I have a `toLowerCase()` in the check so that `'H' === 'h'`. If you want it to match case then remove the `toLowerCase()` function.

Answer (score 0):

ag-Grid now supports this behavior, by default, in version 18.0.0.

https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/?fixVersion=18.0.0